# Menu won't show in Activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have a menu that won't show up in my activity. I have a main activity and a separate activity that contains a list of items I want the user to be able to search through. However, the menu isn't showing up in the activity for searching, so nothing happens when entering in a string for the search.

The goal was the get the menu in the search activity in order to allow the user to search through items using a SearchView and RecyclerView

I'm very new to Android Studio, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the menu for the SearchView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        />


</menu>
```

Here is the layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_search_toolbar"/>



    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/search_menu">


    </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/GoBackbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GO BACK" />

        <!--<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/searchBar"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->
            <!--&lt;!&ndash;app:menu="@menu/search_menu"&ndash;&gt;-->


        <!--</android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>-->

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the toolbar to add to the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is where I inflate the search_menu

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Finally this is part of my Adapter class to filter the items in a RecyclerView

```
 @Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return locationFilter;
}

private Filter locationFilter = new Filter(){
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint){
        List<Location> filteredLocationList = new ArrayList<>();

        if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
            filteredLocationList.addAll(locationListFull);
        } else{
            String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for(Location location : locationListFull){
                if(location.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)){
                    filteredLocationList.add(location);
                }
                // Add another if statement here if we want to be able to search
                // descriptions as well
            }
        }
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredLocationList;
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results){
        locationList.clear();
        locationList.addAll((List)results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Also if there's another way to use the SearchView with RecyclerView besides creating a menu for the SearchView, that would be very helpful. I have tried researching ways to access the SearchView besides through creating a new menu, but haven't found anything useful.

Comment: Use `app:showAsAction="always"` instead of `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't work. It still does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

> Prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown. You can use this method to efficiently enable/disable items or otherwise dynamically modify the contents.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)

You need to override `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and setup your searchview there instead of doing that in `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: I tried to Override onPrepareOptionsMenu to set up the searchview, but it still did not work.